# Using the list of lists called c defined below. Make a new list that contains all of the numbers between 5 and 45 that appear in the list

Tags: python, list

so I'm supposed to create a new list "d" from a list of lists "c", where "d" contains all numbers of "c" between the values of 5 and 45.

`c = [[1,1,12],[2,3,7,23],[54,12,17,90],[43,52,67,9]]`

`d = [x for x in c if x in range(5,45)]`

`print(d)`

I tried this code, and I just get an empty output of

`[]`

Comment: `x` will be a list, which doesn't compare (properly) to the `range(5, 45)` object.

Comment: Please update your question with the expected output.

Comment: I find it helpful sometimes to use regular for loops instead of list comprehensions to troubleshoot or even to develop the list comprehension correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten the list first:

```py
d = [v for x in c for v in x if v in range(5, 45)]
```

In the code you posted, you have `x for x in c` in your list comprehension. Each `x` here is one of the sublists (say, for example `[1,1,12]`). This being a `list` will never satisfy: `x in range(5,45)` since `range()` will be looking for a single integer and not a `list`. Code in the form `x in y` never looks inside `x`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you this worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I am a total noob in python, would you mind explaining why this worked versus what I initially tried?

Answer (score 0):

`x` stands for each list inside your `"list of lists"`. You can unpack `c`:

`d = [x for x in list(itertools.chain(*c)) if x in range(5, 45)]`

Comment: Note that the `list()` isn't necessary: `itertools.chain()` returns an iterable.